# How to prevent sleepiness at study time?

Tags: sleep, mental-health, sleep-deprivation, dizziness, chronic-fatigue-synd.-cfs

I feel sleepiness all time, at the time of study. I try for many types of check up. After observing the test reports the doctors says, 'you are OK, there is no problem with you. I can't understand about your problem.'.

To get rid of this problem is very emergency for me because if i cannot stop this problem then i have to stop my study. It is impossible for me to continue my study with this problem. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in order to avoid sleeping while studying, just follow this steps below:

1.Switch the Lights On. Don't even think about studying in just the lamplight at night.

2.Sit in Front of a Table.

3.No Heavy Meals.

4.Move Around in Your Room

5.Read out Aloud While Studying

http://www.newhealthadvisor.com/How-to-Avoid-Sleep-While-Studying.html